# Eclipse Workspace corrupted

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently corrupted my Eclipse workspace, before a forced restart. I tried different methods to save it, but no one worked.
The projects are gone in Eclipse interface, but they are not gone in disk. 
I tried to copy them to another workspace but they are not working.

I also tried other version and executing "eclipse.exe -clean"

This is in Eclipse Mars.1 
I don t know if this is because of the shutdown... Because this new version of Eclipse sometimes fails...

EDIT: When you try to create a project with the name of one of the corrupted projects, it says the project exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the projects are still on the disk, you should be able to import them.

If you go to File > Import, probably chose General > Existing Projects into Workspace (could instead import Maven projects, git repos etc.), go find the directory that the projects were saved in, select the ones you want, follow the rest of the instructions...

That will get your code back, I don't think you will be able to get back any settings from your workspace, it sounds like they are gone.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!